# WordPress TinyMCE: page crashes when double clicking on <meter> element in Chrome

Tags: html, wordpress, google-chrome, tinymce

While working on a plugin for the wordpress editor, I created a button that allows you to create an HTML `<meter>` element. As I was working on it I noticed by accident that if you double click on it in the Visual Editor in Chrome, the page crashes and gives an "Aw Snap! Something went wrong while displaying this webpage."

I thought maybe it was my plugin, but it doesn't matter. I deactivated it and just created a meter element manually and it consistently crashes. I don't have any other plugins activated and my theme is really bare bones because I use the site for testing. It's fine on Firefox. I tried disabling all my extensions, restarting my computer, clearing cookies and cache...

Anyone have a clue what could be going on here?